# Change XML node with same name?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

everyone!
I have an XML file and need to change the value of a node, specifically the indicated line. The problem i have is that as you can see, there are many  nodes.

How can i change this line? This XML file could be much larger, so i am looking for a solution that would take different amounts of 'launch.file' nodes into account.

The node that will need to be set to True will be identified by the corresponding NAME tag. So if i typed in ULTII, the DISABLED node for that block will be set to True. If i typed in Catl, then the DISABLED node for that block would be changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<SBase.Doc Type="Launch" version="1,0">
  <Descr>Launch</Descr>
  <Filename>run.xml</Filename>
  <Disabled>False</Disabled>
  <Launch.ManualLoad>False</Launch.ManualLoad>
  <Launch.File>
    <Name>Catl</Name>
    <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    <ManualLoad>False</ManualLoad>
    <Path>ft\catl\catl.exe</Path>
  </Launch.File>
  <Launch.File>
    <Disabled>False</Disabled>          <!-- change to True -->
    <ManualLoad>False</ManualLoad>
    <Name>ULTII</Name>
    <Path>F:\ULTII.exe</Path>
    <NewConsole>True</NewConsole>
  </Launch.File>
  <Launch.File>
    <Name>ECA</Name>
    <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    <Path>C:\ECA.exe</Path>
  </Launch.File>
</SBase.Doc>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012, should you need to know.

Thank you to anyone who can help me out on this, i really appreciate it.

Comment: I would make the Name element an attribute and search for the record based off that key.

Comment: Well what is special about that particular element that means you want to set *that* one to be disabled rather than the previous one? What aspect of that Launch.File element is relevant?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Basically, the node that will need to be set to True will be identified by the corresponding NAME tag. So if i typed in ULTII, the DISABLED node for that block will be set to True. If i typed in Catl, then the DISABLED node for that block would be changed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) (see [XDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)).
Assuming that there is the **single** `Launch.File` element with `Name` element with value `"ULTII"`:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(...);

var ultiiElement = document
    .Descendants("Launch.File")
    .Single(fileElement => fileElement.Element("Name").Value == "ULTII");
ultiiElement.Element("Disabled").Value = "True"; // or true.ToString()

document.Save(...);
```

Comment: The NAME element will always be unique, but the name that would need its disabled tag changed would be determined at run time, so i cant really hard-code it. Im pretty new to XML, so i will have a go. Thanks!

Comment: @user2074700, okay, if it works for you, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Heres my method to do what you want

```
private void DisableLaunchFile(string xmlfile, string launchFileName){
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);

  var launchFileElement = doc.Descendants("Launch.File").Where (d => d.Element("Name").Value == lauchFileName);

  launchFileElement.Elements("Disabled").First().Value = true.ToString();

  doc.Save(xmlfile);
}
```

Use it like:

```
string pathToXmlFile = //assign ;

DisableLaunchFile(pathToXmlFile, "Catl");

DisableLaunchFile(pathToXmlFile, "ULTII");
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will do the trick:

```
public void ChangeNode(string name, string filePath)
{

    XDocument xDocument;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        xDocument = XDocument.Parse(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }

    var nodes = xDocument.Descendants("Launch.File");

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var nameNode = node.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault();

        if (nameNode != null && nameNode.Value == name)
        {
            var disabledNode = node.Descendants("Disabled").FirstOrDefault();

            if (disabledNode != null)
            {
                disabledNode.SetValue("True");
            }
        }
    }

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        xDocument.Save(streamWriter);               
    }
}
```

The name you want to pass in is the name of the node that you want to change and the path is the file path to the xml file.  So you might call it like:

```
ChangeNode("ULTII", "C:\\output.xml");
```

You may need to tidy this up a bit like matching the node name invariant of case or culture but it should get you started.